# Метод bs4 видит контент, но не возвращает значение

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Возникла проблема при написании парсера. Есть сайт с базой данных профессиональных спортсменов. Задача парсера состоит в том, чтобы вывести список из подходящих по критериям вариантов. Весь процесс проходил нормально, но в ходе расширения функционала где-то возникла ошибка из-за которой bs4 видит контент, но не может его проанализировать. Заранее благодарен за помощь. Вот код функции с анализом данных:

```
def td_jump(tr_list, min_points, max_points, min_age, max_age, division_ask, min_wins, max_wins, min_loses, max_loses, residence_ask):
    for tr in tr_list[0:25]:
        td_list = tr.find_all('td')
        name = td_list[1].find('a').get('href')
        points = float(td_list[2].text)
        wins_loses = td_list[6].find_all('span')
        wins = int(wins_loses[0].text)
        loses = int(wins_loses[1].text)

        if min_points <= points <= max_points:
            if td_list[5].text == '':
                pass
            else:
                age = int(td_list[5].text)
                if min_age <= age <= max_age:
                    if td_list[4] == '':
                        pass
                    else:
                        division = td_list[4].text
                        division = division.strip()
                        for i in division_ask:
                            if division == i:
                                if min_wins <= wins <= max_wins:
                                    if min_loses <= loses <= max_loses:
                                        if td_list[9].text == '':
                                            pass
                                        else:
                                            residence_full = td_list[9].find_all('a')
                                            if len(residence_full) > 1:

                                                residence = residence_full[-1].text
                                                for i in residence_ask:
                                                    if residence == i:
                                                        boxers.append(name)
                                                        print(name)
                                                    else:
                                                        pass
                                            else:
                                                pass
                                    else:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                    pass
                            else:
                                pass

                else:
                    pass
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Разделяй и властвуй.

Comment: Приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример кода.

Comment: И данные которые ожидаете получить.